# Mvc Web Api Knouck and Json Tree Issue

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have 2 problems. Before I explain my problems I want to share my json result, a little part. [image]

I wanna take all Category Properties(CategoryId,CategorySeoName...) and I write this.

```
public IEnumerable<Category> FindAllCategoryName()
    {
        return CategoryRepository.GetAll().Select(x => new Category
        {
            CategoryName = x.CategoryName
        }).ToList();
    }
```

But it gives an error like this "An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code" and additional information "Category class have a complex type, you don't create Linq to Entities query". I think this problem about ICollection Tales propeties

My second problem is, list of this tales in category. I use knockout.js.

#### talesCrud.js

```
function TalesViewModel() {
var self = this;
self.tales = ko.observableArray();
$.getJSON("/api/tales/kids/", self.tales);}

$(document).ready(function () {
ko.applyBindings(new TalesViewModel());})
```

#### Html

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: tales">
        <li>
            <div>
                <div>Masal Adı</div>
                <span data-bind="text: $data.TaleName"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>İçerik</div>
                <span data-bind="text: $data.Content"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>Ses Dosyası</div>
                <span data-bind="text: $data.VoicePath"></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I didn't take this properties in json result. Because it's have different tree.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should post two questions, will get you answers more easily. The first issue seems fairly generic, and googling for the error message has lots of leads, but we'd really have to see more code, know more variables (whats your db/driver?) to tell more.

As for your second issue, it looks like you're using `$.getJSON` incorrectly. I assume you want to load the JSON into the `tales` array, if so, you should try this instead

```
$.getJSON("/api/tales/kids/", function(data) {
    self.tales(data.Tales);
});
```

It looks correct otherwise.